# clipChildren doesn't work if bottom view has background

Tags: android

I found a weird layout behavior when a view's shadow is clipped by the bottom view if this bottom view has some background, even though `clipChildren` is set to false and it works correctly on the top part. If I remove background from the bottom view or remove `FrameLayout` - the problem resolves. But in this particular problem, I can't do this because the parent layout has its own background and these three views need to have their own background. Also, I can't move all three views into one FrameLayoutbecause they will be separate items in a recycler.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you in advance.

[image: Image Output]

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="asdasdasd" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingHorizontal="24dp">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:elevation="16dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="asdasdasd" />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. A colleague suggested adding translationZ, so the problem was fixed by adding android:outlineProvider="none" and android:translationZ="1dp" to the frameLayout. Thanks, Andrey!

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        android:paddingHorizontal="24dp"
        android:translationZ="1dp">
```